# C# IIS Optimization threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, iis-7.5

We've got math intensive soft (Linear Algebra) that we use on web server (IIS). Process creates 2 or more threads. 10-15 users is OK but with 20-25 users performance decreases. We assume threads interfere each other. Is there any way to configure it in optimal way or rebuild soft to handle threads properly?

OS in Vmware vSphere 5.5
Win 2008 R2 x64 Standard, IIS 7.5, C# 3.5
2 Xeon Quad Core

Comment: Are the two threads per user? Or shared? Define "optimal"? Linear algebra is CPU intensive, so if they are all busy: they are all busy. What is the overall CPU load at that point? Also: are you using work pool threads? Or your own threads? Because saturation / starvation if the thread pool is a thing.

Comment: 2 threads created with new Thread C# command. For Linear algebra we use 100% CPU during matrix computation. Optimal I mean - fully utilize CPU resources without jams. We use default pool threading of IIS. Is there any use to change maximum worker processes parameter?

Comment: If you are using 100% CPU... What do you expect to do differently?

Answer (score -1):

The solution is found by changing the "maximum worker processes" to 10 ApplicationPool
It carries a number of problems with synchronization, but solves the problem of overloading the server and queues.